# Правильно ли сформулировано предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На одном ресурсе, посвященном кино, была такая запись: "Если бы взамен на то, что вы голодаете десять дней, вам предложили встречу с любимым актером, вы бы согласились?"
Так вот, сомнения берет по поводу построения этой фразы. Разве можно сказать: "взамен на то, что..."? Может быть лучше было сказать "взамен того, что вы не едите..." или же вообще "взамен десятидневной голодовки..."?
Как грамматически правильно должна быть построена эта фраза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: "Если бы взамен того, что вы голодаете десять дней, вам предложили встречу с любимым актером, вы бы согласились?"

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ВЗАМЕН. I. нареч.Вместо этого, в обмен. Прислать в. кого-л. другого. Попросить что-л. в. II. предлог. чего. Вместо. В. урока русского языка был проведён урок истории. Выдать справку в. диплома.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) У предлога ВЗАМЕН отмечено сильное управление беспредложным Р.падежом, поэтому соотносительное местоимение в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным ставится только в Р.п.

2) Во многих случаях одно и то же содержание можно выразить с помощью различных форм, в том числе предложенным Вами способом:"Если бы взамен десятидневной голодовки вам предложили встречу с любимым актером, вы бы согласились?" Этот вариант можно считать более удачным.

Answer (score 1):

Автор имел в виду "в **обмен** на то". И это, кстати, было бы гораздо лучше, чем "взамен того".